# [GUZZLE][SYMFONY3] listen guzzle exception event

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, event-listener

First, i apologize for my bad english.

I'm here because i'm looking for some way to listen exception guzzle event to redirect to login page if i receive status code 401.

I found an event "PostTransactionEvent" allowing to get data struct of my response. It makes his job but i can't redirect to login page. It seems `RedirectResponse` method was not executed.

services.yml :

```
    glpi.expire_listener:
    class: GlpiBundle\Expire\ExpireListener
    arguments: ["@router","@request_stack"]
    tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: guzzle_bundle.post_transaction, method: check }
```

ExpireListener.php

```
namespace GlpiBundle\Expire;

use EightPoints\Bundle\GuzzleBundle\Events\GuzzleEventListenerInterface;
use EightPoints\Bundle\GuzzleBundle\Events\PostTransactionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class ExpireListener implements GuzzleEventListenerInterface
{
protected $service_name;

protected $request_stack;

public function __construct($router,$request_stack)
{
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->request_stack = $request_stack;
}

public function check(PostTransactionEvent $event)
{

    $response_transaction = $event->getTransaction();


    $e = new ExpireApi();
    $available = $e->deconnect($response_transaction);

    if ($available) {
       return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('logout'));

    }

    $event->setTransaction($response_transaction);
}

public function setServiceName($serviceName){
    $this->service_name = $serviceName;

}
}
```

request :

```
            $reponse_categories =$client->get('/apirest.php/itilcategory?searchText[itilcategories_id]='.self::ID_CAMPUS_ID,
            [
                "headers"=>
                    [
                        "App-Token"=>TOKEN,
                        "Session-Token"=>SESSION
                    ],
                  'exceptions'=>false
            ]);
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
// redirect to login page
$redResponse = new RedirectResponse( $this->router->generate('login') );
$redResponse->send();
```

Here is the full code:

https://github.com/viher3/yuwik-frontend/blob/develop/src/EventListeners/Guzzle/ExpiredJwt.php

Regards!

Comment: Thank you very much Viher. That's it.

Comment: It's work like i would like to work ! Just one things, my flash is empty after redirect to login page. So Instead of setting flashbah to service, i set it to route controller.